# MIT Intro to Psychology, Raven's Progressive Matrices question

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

[image]

This is from lecture 14 on intelligence.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bihrpOS0qtY&list=PL44ABC9278E2EE706&index=14

Comment: If there's a solution that you think is wrong, you could tell us what it is and what reasoning it uses, so that we don't repeat it. Also, is this an online lecture that you could link?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the answer is

> Option 3, one black diamond

My reasoning is:

> Each row and each column has two black diamonds and two white diamonds. Option 3 completes the pattern.

Comment: This also keeps the pattern of every row (and no column) rot13(orvat n cnyvaqebzr)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: have you considered diagonal patterns?

Comment: @TylerSelden I have not, but with the row and column patterns being this strong, that felt like overthinking it.

Comment: @samm82 Interestingly the columns are all "repeating patterns" in some sense: WBWB, BBWW, and WBWB.